# Связанные сервера и XML

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть 2 связанных сервера.

Когда я пытаюсь сделать запрос к БД другого сервера к таблице, где есть поле XML, которое я даже не выбираю, то получаю ошибку о том, что запросы к таблицам с XML делать запрещено.

Можно ли это как-нибудь обойти?

Есть вариант через Export/Import все импортировать на сервер и делать запрос, но это лишнее время...

Comment: Напишите, что не устраивает в ответе, или отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить таблицу с xml-столбцом через удаленный запрос необходимо на удаленном сервере создать представление без xml-столбца (если он не нужен) или преобразовав его в `varchar(max)/nvarchar(max)`:

```
CREATE VIEW xml_view AS 
SELECT CAST(xml_column as varchar(max)) as xml_column FROM xml_table
```

Затем можно использовать удаленный запрос к этому представлению.

```
SELECT * FROM REMOTE_DB.database.dbo.xml_view
```

Если на основном сервере необходим столбец именно типа `xml`, а не varchar(max)/nvarchar(max), то дополнительно можно использовать запрос к представлению через `openquery`:

```
SELECT cast(xml_column as xml) as xml_column 
FROM OPENQUERY(REMOTE_DB, 'SELECT xml_column FROM xml_view')
```

Также можно напрямую обращаться к удаленной таблице с xml, используя `openquery`:

```
SELECT CAST(xml_column AS xml) as xml_column 
FROM OPENQUERY(REMOTE_DB, 'select cast(xml_column as varchar(max)) as xml_column from xml_table') xml_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, скастите поле к NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Само присутствие колонки к XML не дает запрашивать эту таблицу, каст не поможет.

Comment: Ну, вообще, поможет. Если скастить на стороне сервера-источника (будь то запрос в `OPENQUERY` или представление), что я и имел в виду. Но минус заслужен, т.к. я не уточнил